# ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] When using Selenium Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium

Hello i have a simple problem that has suddenly developed on my code, until yesterday it was working correctly, this means it opened a web page and entered login details (is a test for a bigger app), however now whenever it tries to connect to the login page i get a timeout error. I have updated Selenium and Chrome Web Driver to the latest and it is still failing to connect, this is my code:

```
#importing libraries, selenium is the base of the script, time to add pauses when appropiate or necessary and select and request will stay until i determine that they are not necessary for the final script.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
import requests
#defining browser to use the webdriver with chrome, and navigating to Makor.
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://mrmprod/Login.aspx')
```

And this is the complete error code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\Input
>   test.py", line 7, in 
>           browser = webdriver.Chrome()
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py",
>   line 69, in **init**
>           desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 92, in **init**
>           self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 179, in start_session
>           response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 234, in execute
>           response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 407, in execute
>           return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 439, in _request
>           resp = self._conn.getresponse()
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 1197, in getresponse
>           response.begin()
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 297, in begin
>           version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py",
>   line 258, in _read_status
>           line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
>         File "C:\Users\AMSUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py",
>   line 575, in readinto
>           return self._sock.recv_into(b)
>       ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I asked the network administrator and he has told me that there hasn't being any change on the network settings since i originally got the code working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reviewed the aforementioned then do the following steps:

You have to include inside the parenthesis the chromedriver path.

Check the code below:

**CODE SAMPLE FOR WINDOWS OS**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\User\\YOUR_USERS_NAME\\YOUR_PATH\\chromedriver.exe')
```

**CODE SAMPLE FOR LINUX OS**

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('usr\\bin\\YOUR_PATH\\chromedriver')
```